# .htaccess file is not working on a site for auto-generation of files

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to debug an issue with my .htaccess file.

I have a directory which is `/wp-content/plugins/lot-wp-app/content` which contains a .htaccess like so:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../generate.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And I don't know why it has stopped working, it may be due to it being invalid.

generate.php is located at `/wp-content/plugins/lot-wp-app/generate.php`

The idea is that an Android app would request `/wp-content/plugins/lot-wp-app/content/posts-etc.json` and do reduce server load, it would load that file if it existed. However, we delete the cache when a new post is made so that it is fresh (but it's generated on-demand, so you can browse our history nicely)

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

To start, `RewriteEngine On` should be on its own line.

Comment: It was, strange.... it seems putting it here has broke it

Comment: Maybe that's part of the problem - does your .htaccess have mixed line endings?